# "[Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory" on Geoip2() in Django with uWSGI

Tags: django, memory, uwsgi, geoip, geoip2

The following code runs successfully in `manage.py shell`:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geoip2 import GeoIP2
g = GeoIP2()
```

If I start the server manually with `manage.py runserver`
and put the code in my Django view, it also runs fine.

My Django application is hosted with `uWSGI` and `Nginx` as reverse proxy.
Both `uWSGI` and `Nginx` run with `www-data` user.

Here is the exception that I get when running on `uWSGI`:

```
...
File "/home/myuser/Env/virtenv/myproject/index/views.py" in index
  28.     g = GeoIP2()

File "/home/myuser/Env/virtenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geoip2/base.py" in __init__
  95.                 self._city = geoip2.database.Reader(city_db, mode=cache)

File "/home/myuser/Env/virtenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geoip2/database.py" in __init__
  82.         self._db_reader = maxminddb.open_database(filename, mode)

File "/home/myuser/Env/virtenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/maxminddb/__init__.py" in open_database
  37.         return maxminddb.reader.Reader(database, mode)

File "/home/myuser/Env/virtenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/maxminddb/reader.py" in __init__
  52.                     db_file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)

Exception Type: error at /
Exception Value: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

Local variables are:

```
Variable    Value
database    '/home/myuser/Env/virtenv/myproject/geoip/GeoLite2-City.mmdb'
db_file     <closed file '/home/myuser/Env/virtenv/myproject/geoip/GeoLite2-City.mmdb',     mode 'rb' at 0x7f8c5cf5d390>
mode        0
self        <maxminddb.reader.Reader object at 0x7f8c5cf5f550>
```

I use Virtualbox and my guest OS is `Ubuntu 16.04`. I have 4GB swap file there. 
If I free up some RAM the problem persists.
This shouldn't be a memory issue on OS level, though, 
as I can create the GeoIP2 object in the shell and also if I run the server manually.

Next thing I checked is that the `geoip` directory in my project is owned by `www-data` and has 775.
Both files inside (`GeoLite2-City.mmdb` and `GeoLite2-Country.mmdb`) are also owned by `www-data` and have 774.

`/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service` contains:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown www-data:www-data /run/uwsgi'
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`/etc/uwsgi/sites/my_site.ini` contains:

```
[uwsgi]

project = myproject
base = /home/myuser
home = %(base)/Env/virtenv/%(project)

binary-path = /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
chdir = %(home)
chmod-socket = 660
chown-socket = www-data:www-data
#emperor = true
#enable-threads = true
gid = www-data
limit-as = 1024
logto = /tmp/uwsgi.log
master = true
module = myproject.wsgi:application
pidfile = /opt/logs/uwsgi/master.pid
# number of cores on machine
processes = 2
python-path = %(home)
py-autoreload = 2
socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
uid = www-data
vacuum = true
virtualenv = %(base)/Env/virtenv
vhost = true
workers = 4

env = AWS_KEY=***************
env = AWS_SECRET=***************
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings.local
env = GMAIL_PASS=***************
env = PSQL_PASS=***************
env = SECRET_KEY=*********************************************
```

I am wondering where the limitation of `uWSGI` is?

Comment: can you monitor memory usage of VM with something like htop ?

Comment: I checked with htop and I had 1.5GB free RAM left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`limit-as = 512` in uWSGI's `ini` file was the culprit. Doubling it to `1024` mb resolves the problem.

From the official uWSGI 2 documentation [here](http://uwsgi-docs-additions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#limit-as):

> limit-as
>
> Argument: number
>
> Limit process address space (vsz) (in megabytes).
>
> Limits the address space usage of each uWSGI (worker) process using
>   POSIX/UNIX setrlimit(). For example, limit-as 256 will disallow uWSGI
>   processes to grow over 256MB of address space. Address space is the
>   virtual memory a process has access to. It does not correspond to
>   physical memory. Read and understand this page before enabling this
>   option: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory